# I need a link to animate slowly on hover using jquery, and this does not work

Tags: jquery

```
$("#link").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "black"}, "slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "white"}, "slow");
});
```

any suggestions? I want the link to animate slowly instead of immediately with the css hover property.

Comment: Have you included [jquery-ui.js](http://jqueryui.com/)? The core jQuery library doesn't animate colours. Have you run the above code _after_ the `#link` element has been added to the DOM (e.g., in a document ready handler, or if the element is added dynamically you'd need to run that code after it is added)? Take care of those details and your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/4dzhB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use "slow" even-**

```
$("#link").hover(function(){
  $(this).animate({ color: '#fed900'}, "slow");
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({ color: '#000000'}, "slow"); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/ANUT3/591/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#link").hover(function(){
  $(this).animate({ color: '#3d3d3d'}, 4000);
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({ color: '#000000'}, 4000); 
});
```

use milliseconds there..

this is the syntax for animate

> $(selector).animate({params},speed,callback);

where speed can be : slow/fast/milliseconds

Comment: it still does not work with replacing the "slow" with 1000... is there some other syntax i am missing? in the style sheet i have the a:link and a:visited set, but a:hover is not... I'm really confused why this doesn't work.

Comment: The string `"slow"` is also accepted by `.animate()` - if it doesn't work then there is some other problem that switching to a numeric value will not solve.