# Change speed of jquery link hover

Tags: jquery, performance, hover

I have a simple website where the body background changes into an image when i hover on a link. Now i want to slow down the hover speed. Does anyone know how to get this working? I have searched a bit, but couldnt get it working. Thanks in advance!

This is the code:

```
<a href="#" id="first">link</a>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#first").hover(function () {

  $("body").css("background-image", 'url("img/imageurl.jpg")');

}, function()
{   
  $("body").css("background-image", 'none');
}

);
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15491941/8157693

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need a link to animate slowly on hover using jquery, and this does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491805/i-need-a-link-to-animate-slowly-on-hover-using-jquery-and-this-does-not-work)

Comment: maybe its simple, but i dont get that code to work with my code..

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will work**
Use animate function instead of css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#first").hover(function () {

  $("div").animate({"background-color": "yellow"},5000);

}, function()
{   
  $("div").animate("background-color": "red"},5000)
}

);
</script>
```